# How to fix overlapping cell background in kableExtra when knitting to PDF?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I'm creating a table with `kableExtra` to include in my R Markdown report which is knitted to PDF. I've used the `cell_spec()` function from `kableExtra` to apply some simple conditional formatting to a few of the columns which works fine. However, when I knit to PDF, the result is an oddly formatted cell background which overlaps slightly with my row group headers (see image below). Its quite annoying that this happens, so I'm wondering if anyone has any tricks that I can add to my example code below that can fix this?

I'm quite new to coding in LaTeX and still don't really understand the language, so any help is really appreciated! Thanks.

[image]

````
---
title: >
  `\vspace{-1.8cm}`{=latex}
header-includes: 
 - \usepackage{geometry}
 - \geometry{top=0.1in,left=0.1in,bottom=0.1in,right=0.1in}
 - \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
 - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 - \pagestyle{fancy}
 - \fancyhf{}
 - \addtolength{\headheight}{3.0cm}
 - \rhead{\LARGE Vertical Alignment of Header Text}
 - \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
 - \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
mainfont: SourceSansPro
output: pdf_document
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo = FALSE,
  message = FALSE,
  warning = FALSE,
  dev = "cairo_pdf"
  )
```

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r cars}
# Create example data.
set.seed(1)
x <- paste0("var", 1:10)
d <- data.frame(name = paste("Player", LETTERS[1:25]))
d[x] <- round(rnorm(25, 100, 30), 1)
d$group = rep(paste("Group", 1:5), each = 5)
```

```{r}
# Apply cell_spec() to a few columns.
tbl <- d %>%
  mutate(across(var5:var9,
                ~cell_spec(.x,
                           background = case_when(
                             .x > mean(.x) + sd(.x) ~ "#EAE2F6",
                             .x < mean(.x) - sd(.x) ~ "#FEFEDA",
                             .default = "white"
                             )
                           )
                ))
```

```{r}
# Table output.
kbl(tbl[, 1:11],
    booktabs = TRUE,
    escape = FALSE,
    align = c("l", rep("c", ncol(tbl) - 1))) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position"),
                font_size = 8.5) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Header 1" = 4, "Header 2" = 3,
                     "Header" = 3)) %>%
  pack_rows(index = table(fct_inorder(tbl$group)), background = "#ED1B2F",
            color = "white", bold = TRUE)
```
````